# How to map child entities in a reusable manner?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to map an EF entity to an entity more suitable for performing business logic operations. To do so, I am using this expression:

```
var phoneMapper = phone => new BasePhone
{
    Id = phone.Id,
    Number = phone.Number,
    PhoneType = phoneTypeMapper(phone.PhoneType) //Pseudo-Code
}
```

In this example, the phone type class should have a mapping of its own:

```
var phoneTypeMapper = phoneType => new BasePhoneType
{
    Id = phoneType.Id,
    Name = phoneType.Name
}
```

I want to use `phoneTypeMapper` within the definition of `phoneMapper`, how can I do so? I know this is easy to do with a collection:

```
var phoneMapper = phone => new BasePhone
{
    Id = phoneType.Id,
    Name = phoneType.Name,
    //Now a phone has many phone types
    PhoneTypes = phone.PhoneTypes.Select(phoneTypeMapper)
}
```

Is there a way to do this for a non-enumerable property?

**EDIT**

I should also mention that I would like for this to not collapse the query until the parent query has collapsed. I.E. I want to just jam this into a select and not have it hit the database every time it needs to pull record status data.

Comment: `AutoMapper` library?

Comment: I also like explicit and implicit operators

Comment: One of the reasons for the mapping is to avoid creating a direct translation from the data model to the business model. Some entities which exist in the data model may need to be aggregated for the business model, and many-many relationships would need middle-men tables if there is a property on the relationship table.